# Is there a difference between the movement controls in Okami and Okami HD?

Tags: okami, okami-hd

So I have recently downloaded Okami HD, and I have noticed that the directional input seems to be a bit clunkier than in the original. I.e. I can only travel in 45 degree directions.

I have come up with an alternative in the meantime, (rotating the camera to allow for smoother cornering). The only problem is that if I turn too sharply too suddenly, it ruins my sprint. (This is not new, I have tested the original and the same thing happens).

I should also note I am not using a standard PS3 controller, but I have not had this issue with other games (Tested with Gran Turismo 5, Infamous 2, Crash Bandicoot series, Spyro series).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the only changes are really the graphics and the added trophy and move support. Even reviewers who played the game on PS2 haven't mentioned any changes apart from that